# Received unregistered task of type 'djcelery_email_send'

Tags: django, celery

I cannot run django-celery in daemon mode, it said `Received unregistered task of type 'djcelery_email_send'`, while it works when `python manage.py celery worker`, please help.

I am running celery 3.1, with django-celery, django-celery-email on Ubuntu server 14.04. My django settings is in proj/settings/production.py.

Daemon mode of django-celery is init script init.d.
/etc/init.d/celeryd is downloaded from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/celery/celery/3.1/extra/generic-init.d/celeryd and it is as below:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
# ============================================
#  celeryd - Starts the Celery worker daemon.
# ============================================
#
# :Usage: /etc/init.d/celeryd {start|stop|force-reload|restart|try-restart|status}
# :Configuration file: /etc/default/celeryd
#
# See http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html#generic-init-scripts


### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          celeryd
# Required-Start:    $network $local_fs $remote_fs
# Required-Stop:     $network $local_fs $remote_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: celery task worker daemon
### END INIT INFO
#
#
# To implement separate init scripts, copy this script and give it a different
# name:
# I.e., if my new application, "little-worker" needs an init, I
# should just use:
#
#   cp /etc/init.d/celeryd /etc/init.d/little-worker
#
# You can then configure this by manipulating /etc/default/little-worker.
#
VERSION=10.1
echo "celery init v${VERSION}."
if [ $(id -u) -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Error: This program can only be used by the root user."
    echo "       Unprivileged users must use the 'celery multi' utility, "
    echo "       or 'celery worker --detach'."
    exit 1
fi

origin_is_runlevel_dir () {
    set +e
    dirname $0 | grep -q "/etc/rc.\.d"
    echo $?
}

# Can be a runlevel symlink (e.g. S02celeryd)
if [ $(origin_is_runlevel_dir) -eq 0 ]; then
    SCRIPT_FILE=$(readlink "$0")
else
    SCRIPT_FILE="$0"
fi
SCRIPT_NAME="$(basename "$SCRIPT_FILE")"

DEFAULT_USER="celery"
DEFAULT_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%n.pid"
DEFAULT_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%n.log"
DEFAULT_LOG_LEVEL="INFO"
DEFAULT_NODES="celery"
DEFAULT_CELERYD="-m celery worker --detach"

CELERY_DEFAULTS=${CELERY_DEFAULTS:-"/etc/default/${SCRIPT_NAME}"}

# Make sure executable configuration script is owned by root
_config_sanity() {
    local path="$1"
    local owner=$(ls -ld "$path" | awk '{print $3}')
    local iwgrp=$(ls -ld "$path" | cut -b 6)
    local iwoth=$(ls -ld "$path" | cut -b 9)

    if [ "$(id -u $owner)" != "0" ]; then
        echo "Error: Config script '$path' must be owned by root!"
        echo
        echo "Resolution:"
        echo "Review the file carefully and make sure it has not been "
        echo "modified with mailicious intent.  When sure the "
        echo "script is safe to execute with superuser privileges "
        echo "you can change ownership of the script:"
        echo "    $ sudo chown root '$path'"
        exit 1
    fi

    if [ "$iwoth" != "-" ]; then  # S_IWOTH
        echo "Error: Config script '$path' cannot be writable by others!"
        echo
        echo "Resolution:"
        echo "Review the file carefully and make sure it has not been "
        echo "modified with malicious intent.  When sure the "
        echo "script is safe to execute with superuser privileges "
        echo "you can change the scripts permissions:"
        echo "    $ sudo chmod 640 '$path'"
        exit 1
    fi
    if [ "$iwgrp" != "-" ]; then  # S_IWGRP
        echo "Error: Config script '$path' cannot be writable by group!"
        echo
        echo "Resolution:"
        echo "Review the file carefully and make sure it has not been "
        echo "modified with malicious intent.  When sure the "
        echo "script is safe to execute with superuser privileges "
        echo "you can change the scripts permissions:"
        echo "    $ sudo chmod 640 '$path'"
        exit 1
    fi
}

if [ -f "$CELERY_DEFAULTS" ]; then
    _config_sanity "$CELERY_DEFAULTS"
    echo "Using config script: $CELERY_DEFAULTS"
    . "$CELERY_DEFAULTS"
fi

# Sets --app argument for CELERY_BIN
CELERY_APP_ARG=""
if [ ! -z "$CELERY_APP" ]; then
    CELERY_APP_ARG="--app=$CELERY_APP"
fi

CELERYD_USER=${CELERYD_USER:-$DEFAULT_USER}

# Set CELERY_CREATE_DIRS to always create log/pid dirs.
CELERY_CREATE_DIRS=${CELERY_CREATE_DIRS:-0}
CELERY_CREATE_RUNDIR=$CELERY_CREATE_DIRS
CELERY_CREATE_LOGDIR=$CELERY_CREATE_DIRS
if [ -z "$CELERYD_PID_FILE" ]; then
    CELERYD_PID_FILE="$DEFAULT_PID_FILE"
    CELERY_CREATE_RUNDIR=1
fi
if [ -z "$CELERYD_LOG_FILE" ]; then
    CELERYD_LOG_FILE="$DEFAULT_LOG_FILE"
    CELERY_CREATE_LOGDIR=1
fi

CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL:-${CELERYD_LOGLEVEL:-$DEFAULT_LOG_LEVEL}}
CELERY_BIN=${CELERY_BIN:-"celery"}
CELERYD_MULTI=${CELERYD_MULTI:-"$CELERY_BIN multi"}
CELERYD_NODES=${CELERYD_NODES:-$DEFAULT_NODES}

export CELERY_LOADER

if [ -n "$2" ]; then
    CELERYD_OPTS="$CELERYD_OPTS $2"
fi

CELERYD_LOG_DIR=`dirname $CELERYD_LOG_FILE`
CELERYD_PID_DIR=`dirname $CELERYD_PID_FILE`

# Extra start-stop-daemon options, like user/group.
if [ -n "$CELERYD_CHDIR" ]; then
    DAEMON_OPTS="$DAEMON_OPTS --workdir=$CELERYD_CHDIR"
fi


check_dev_null() {
    if [ ! -c /dev/null ]; then
        echo "/dev/null is not a character device!"
        exit 75  # EX_TEMPFAIL
    fi
}


maybe_die() {
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Exiting: $* (errno $?)"
        exit 77  # EX_NOPERM
    fi
}

create_default_dir() {
    if [ ! -d "$1" ]; then
        echo "- Creating default directory: '$1'"
        mkdir -p "$1"
        maybe_die "Couldn't create directory $1"
        echo "- Changing permissions of '$1' to 02755"
        chmod 02755 "$1"
        maybe_die "Couldn't change permissions for $1"
        if [ -n "$CELERYD_USER" ]; then
            echo "- Changing owner of '$1' to '$CELERYD_USER'"
            chown "$CELERYD_USER" "$1"
            maybe_die "Couldn't change owner of $1"
        fi
        if [ -n "$CELERYD_GROUP" ]; then
            echo "- Changing group of '$1' to '$CELERYD_GROUP'"
            chgrp "$CELERYD_GROUP" "$1"
            maybe_die "Couldn't change group of $1"
        fi
    fi
}


check_paths() {
    if [ $CELERY_CREATE_LOGDIR -eq 1 ]; then
        create_default_dir "$CELERYD_LOG_DIR"
    fi
    if [ $CELERY_CREATE_RUNDIR -eq 1 ]; then
        create_default_dir "$CELERYD_PID_DIR"
    fi
}

create_paths() {
    create_default_dir "$CELERYD_LOG_DIR"
    create_default_dir "$CELERYD_PID_DIR"
}

export PATH="${PATH:+$PATH:}/usr/sbin:/sbin"


_get_pidfiles () {
    # note: multi < 3.1.14 output to stderr, not stdout, hence the redirect.
    ${CELERYD_MULTI} expand "${CELERYD_PID_FILE}" ${CELERYD_NODES} 2>&1
}


_get_pids() {
    found_pids=0
    my_exitcode=0

    for pidfile in $(_get_pidfiles); do
        local pid=`cat "$pidfile"`
        local cleaned_pid=`echo "$pid" | sed -e 's/[^0-9]//g'`
        if [ -z "$pid" ] || [ "$cleaned_pid" != "$pid" ]; then
            echo "bad pid file ($pidfile)"
            one_failed=true
            my_exitcode=1
        else
            found_pids=1
            echo "$pid"
        fi

    if [ $found_pids -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "${SCRIPT_NAME}: All nodes down"
        exit $my_exitcode
    fi
    done
}


_chuid () {
    su "$CELERYD_USER" -c "$CELERYD_MULTI $*"
}


start_workers () {
    if [ ! -z "$CELERYD_ULIMIT" ]; then
        ulimit $CELERYD_ULIMIT
    fi
    _chuid $* start $CELERYD_NODES $DAEMON_OPTS     \
                 --pidfile="$CELERYD_PID_FILE"      \
                 --logfile="$CELERYD_LOG_FILE"      \
                 --loglevel="$CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL"    \
                 $CELERY_APP_ARG                    \
                 $CELERYD_OPTS
}


dryrun () {
    (C_FAKEFORK=1 start_workers --verbose)
}


stop_workers () {
    _chuid stopwait $CELERYD_NODES --pidfile="$CELERYD_PID_FILE"
}


restart_workers () {
    _chuid restart $CELERYD_NODES $DAEMON_OPTS      \
                   --pidfile="$CELERYD_PID_FILE"    \
                   --logfile="$CELERYD_LOG_FILE"    \
                   --loglevel="$CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL"  \
                   $CELERY_APP_ARG                  \
                   $CELERYD_OPTS
}


kill_workers() {
    _chuid kill $CELERYD_NODES --pidfile="$CELERYD_PID_FILE"
}


restart_workers_graceful () {
    echo "WARNING: Use with caution in production"
    echo "The workers will attempt to restart, but they may not be able to."
    local worker_pids=
    worker_pids=`_get_pids`
    [ "$one_failed" ] && exit 1

    for worker_pid in $worker_pids; do
        local failed=
        kill -HUP $worker_pid 2> /dev/null || failed=true
        if [ "$failed" ]; then
            echo "${SCRIPT_NAME} worker (pid $worker_pid) could not be restarted"
            one_failed=true
        else
            echo "${SCRIPT_NAME} worker (pid $worker_pid) received SIGHUP"
        fi
    done

    [ "$one_failed" ] && exit 1 || exit 0
}


check_status () {
    my_exitcode=0
    found_pids=0

    local one_failed=
    for pidfile in $(_get_pidfiles); do
        if [ ! -r $pidfile ]; then
            echo "${SCRIPT_NAME} down: no pidfiles found"
            one_failed=true
            break
        fi

        local node=`basename "$pidfile" .pid`
        local pid=`cat "$pidfile"`
        local cleaned_pid=`echo "$pid" | sed -e 's/[^0-9]//g'`
        if [ -z "$pid" ] || [ "$cleaned_pid" != "$pid" ]; then
            echo "bad pid file ($pidfile)"
            one_failed=true
        else
            local failed=
            kill -0 $pid 2> /dev/null || failed=true
            if [ "$failed" ]; then
                echo "${SCRIPT_NAME} (node $node) (pid $pid) is down, but pidfile exists!"
                one_failed=true
            else
                echo "${SCRIPT_NAME} (node $node) (pid $pid) is up..."
            fi
        fi
    done

    [ "$one_failed" ] && exit 1 || exit 0
}


case "$1" in
    start)
        check_dev_null
        check_paths
        start_workers
    ;;

    stop)
        check_dev_null
        check_paths
        stop_workers
    ;;

    reload|force-reload)
        echo "Use restart"
    ;;

    status)
        check_status
    ;;

    restart)
        check_dev_null
        check_paths
        restart_workers
    ;;

    graceful)
        check_dev_null
        restart_workers_graceful
    ;;

    kill)
        check_dev_null
        kill_workers
    ;;

    dryrun)
        check_dev_null
        dryrun
    ;;

    try-restart)
        check_dev_null
        check_paths
        restart_workers
    ;;

    create-paths)
        check_dev_null
        create_paths
    ;;

    check-paths)
        check_dev_null
        check_paths
    ;;

    *)
        echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/${SCRIPT_NAME} {start|stop|restart|graceful|kill|dryrun|create-paths}"
        exit 64  # EX_USAGE
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

/etc/default/celeryd is as following:

```
CELERYD_NODES="proj"
#   but you can also start multiple and configure settings
#   for each in CELERYD_OPTS (see `celery multi --help` for examples):
#CELERYD_NODES="worker1 worker2 worker3"
#   alternatively, you can specify the number of nodes to start:
#CELERYD_NODES=10
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='proj.settings.production'
export PYTHONPATH='$PYTHONPATH:/home/ubuntu/proj'

# Absolute or relative path to the 'celery' command:
#CELERY_BIN="/usr/local/bin/celery"
CELERY_BIN="/home/ubuntu/virtualenv/proj/bin/celery"

# App instance to use
# comment out this line if you don't use an app
#CELERY_APP="proj"
# or fully qualified:
#CELERY_APP="proj.tasks:app"

# Where to chdir at start.
CELERYD_CHDIR="/home/ubuntu/proj/"

# Extra command-line arguments to the worker
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=8"

# %N will be replaced with the first part of the nodename.
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%N.log"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%N.pid"

# Workers should run as an unprivileged user.
#   You need to create this user manually (or you can choose
#   a user/group combination that already exists, e.g. nobody).
CELERYD_USER="ubuntu"
CELERYD_GROUP="ubuntu"

# If enabled pid and log directories will be created if missing,
# and owned by the userid/group configured.
CELERY_CREATE_DIRS=1
```

error log snippet of /var/log/celery/proj.log:

```
If you depend on pickle then you should set a setting to disable this
warning and to be sure that everything will continue working
when you upgrade to Celery 3.2::

    CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['pickle', 'json', 'msgpack', 'yaml']

You must only enable the serializers that you will actually use.


  warnings.warn(CDeprecationWarning(W_PICKLE_DEPRECATED))
[2016-06-07 07:22:10,699: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//
[2016-06-07 07:22:10,708: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2016-06-07 07:22:11,715: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2016-06-07 07:22:11,722: WARNING/MainProcess] proj@ip-172-31-20-158 ready.
[2016-06-07 07:22:44,464: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type 'djcelery_email_send'.
The message has been ignored and discarded.

Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
Or maybe you are using relative imports?
Please see  for more information.

The full contents of the message body was:
{'errbacks': None, 'callbacks': None, 'retries': 0, 'taskset': None, 'expires': None, 'timelimit': (None, None), 'args': ([{'cc': [], 'to': ['cjh@yahoo.com', '649858321@qq.com', 'xu_jordan@163.com', '123456@qq.com'], 'alternatives': [], 'bcc': [], 'attachments': [], 'reply_to': [], 'headers': {}, 'subject': 'A show: i is on the way', 'from_email': 'no-reply@angelscity.co', 'body': 'i'}], {}), 'eta': None, 'task': 'djcelery_email_send', 'chord': None, 'kwargs': {}, 'id': '9b108b79-4ac9-4039-bca0-486c0241930f', 'utc': True} (587b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenv/proj/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 456, in on_task_received
    strategies[name](message, body,
KeyError: 'djcelery_email_send'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally moved to supervisord and it works.

Here is detail for anybody who may meet the same problem.

- Install supervisord: `sudo apt-get install supervisord`. There are some other options to install it, such as easy_install, but make sure your easy_install is for python 2.x. supervisord only supports python 2.4+ instead of python 3.
- add ceelryd.conf to /etc/supervisor/conf.d as following:

  ```
  [program:celery]
  ;command=pythonpath manage.pypath celery worker --settings=proj.settings
  command=/home/username/virtualenvs/projenv/bin/python /home/username/proj/manage.py celery worker --settings=proj.settings

  environment=PYTHONPATH='/home/username/virtualenvs/projenv'

  directory=/home/username/virtualenvs/projenv
  user=username
  numprocs=1
  stdout_logfile=/var/log/celeryd.log
  stderr_logfile=/var/log/celeryd.log
  autostart=true
  autorestart=true
  startsecs=10

  ; Need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown.
  ; Increase this if you have very long running tasks.
  stopwaitsecs = 600

  ; if rabbitmq is supervised, set its priority higher
  ; so it starts first
  priority=998
  ```
- reread and update supervisor: `sudo supervisorctl reread && sudo supervisorctl update`
- restart celery: `sudo supervisorctl restart celery`